# Python - Django - activate() returns None

Tags: python, django, web-applications, heroku, authentication

Okay, so I'm trying to create a log in with Django.

from views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import *
from forms import UserRegistrationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
import pprint
import utils
import models
from django.http import HttpResponse
import views
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url    

def login_user(request):
    state = "Please log in below..."
    username = password = ''

    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if not user.is_verified:
                state = "Please check your e-mail to verify your account."
            elif user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
            else:
                state = "Your account is not active, please contact the site admin."
        else:
            state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."

        return render_to_response('myapp/dashboard.html', {'state': state}, RequestContext(request))

    else:
        return render_to_response('myapp/login.html', RequestContext(request))
```

My login template (login.html):

```
<h3>Login</h3><hr />

            <form action="/login/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
                {% if next %}
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                {% endif %}

                username:
                <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username }}" /><br />
                password:
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />

                <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Log In" />
            </form>
```

I'm using a basic SQLite3 to get everything figured out. python manage.py syncdb runs with no problems

from settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'tempDB'
    }
}
```

When I log into my admin site I see the user:

> username: nick 
>   password: the hashed version of nick

When I insert a break (using PBD) I was able to see that the app goes through the login_user view.

```
> ...myapp/myapp/views.py(52)login_user()
-> state = "Please log in below..."
(Pdb) n
> ...myapp/myapp/views.py(53)login_user()
-> username = password = ''
(Pdb) print username
*** NameError: name 'username' is not defined
(Pdb) n
> ...myapp/myapp/views.py(55)login_user()
-> if request.POST:
(Pdb) print username

(Pdb) n
> ...myapp/myapp/views.py(56)login_user()
-> username = request.POST.get('username')
(Pdb) print username

(Pdb) n
> ...myapp/myapp/views.py(57)login_user()
-> password = request.POST.get('password')
(Pdb) print username
nick
(Pdb) n
> ...myapp/myapp/views.py(59)login_user()
-> user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
(Pdb) print password
nick
(Pdb) n
> ...myapp/myapp/views.py(61)login_user()
-> if user is not None:
(Pdb) print user
None
```

This shows that it gets the username 'nick' and the password 'nick' (the settings that I set the account up with) however the problem I run into is that authenticate is still returning None which means SOMETHING is not set up correctly / is not working.

After that login_user view the 'state' prints "Your username and/or password were incorrect." as told to do in views.py

I would greatly appreciate it if someone would be able to help me out!

Comment: Before implementing your own login page, have you tried using the builtin login page and tested that it works? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views

Answer (score 0):

*(Replied on G+ as well)*

From your pdb session:

```
(Pdb) print password
nick
```

If that's what happens, there's a problem there, don't you agree?
Also, I'd do away with the initialization of the vars and do this instead:

```
username = request.POST.get('username')
password = request.POST.get('password')
if username and password:
    # Your code
```

request.POST.get will work anyway (POST is always initialized as a QueryDict) and the get() returns None if the key is not found, so you won't get any errors - and it might be easier for you to see what's going on.﻿